# Suggestion: use type="url" on the openid URL input field

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, openid, mobile-web

Using type="url" instead of type="text" would make life a lot easier when logging in via iPhones and Android Phones (mobile Safari, in general).

Other browsers ignore it and pretend it's type="text", so no harm done.

See http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#type-url for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I added `type="url"` to the `<input>` field on the login page.

edit: Backing this change out. Causing lots of spurious bug reports from new-ish browsers that enforce URLs rigidly to "must start with http://" rather than using it as an input aid.

Comment: From the source: "There is no markup required to activate HTML5 form validation; it is on by default. To turn it off, use the `novalidate` attribute." Can we have it back now?

Comment: @soumya nice! that will definitely help!

Answer (score 0):

OpenID identifier can be not only URL, look at [XRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Resource_Identifier). Currently, it's impossible to enter such IDs in Google Chrome 5.0. It's exotic, yes...