# Suggestion: use type="text" on the openid URL input field

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, openid, authentication

Earlier I can enter just domain name in custom openid filed on login page and that was working.

Now, some client validation was added and I need always enter full http address to login.
For example, now I need to enter http://team23.ru instead of team23.ru.

Comment: erm... ok? so enter the full http address?

Comment: 16 symbols against 9. Almost two times more. Dumb job can be done computers not humans.

Comment: @derigel: See if you can get your openID provider to lengthen their URL and the ratio will go down :)

Comment: @jason Overall UI experience is compound from such small issues.
Before it was working, I don't ask something new, just revert it back.
Just one example - are you always enter full http address of site in your browser? I know the answer ;)

Comment: So, this is now STATUS-REVERTED, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, all need to do by myself ;)

I've wrote greasemonkey script that changes type of input field for OpenID identifier from "url" to regular "text". It removes validation for full URL in Google Chrome 5.0 (and other browsers supporting HTML 5).
Works on all trilogy sites.

Here is the script http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/76767

Comment: you know that we changed it from "text" to "url" because of [this request here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35070/suggestion-use-typeurl-on-the-openid-url-input-field), right? So now we change it back? Make up your minds..

Comment: Type "url" is good and right in theory, but it's annoying in practice. :) I am fine with current state, with greasemonkey script.

Comment: One more thought - OpenID identifier can be not only URL, look at XRI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Resource_Identifier)

Answer (score 0):

what? I can enter **team23.ru** in this page

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login

then press `enter` and it works fine, I am prompted for login.

(this also works on the question page itself when not logged in -- tested and confirmed.)

edit: going back to `type="text"` as `type="url"` is too rigidly enforced in new browsers, rather than being a simple input aid.

Comment: Ok, I've found the issue. It's working in FF, but not working in latest Google Chrome.
And I am pretty sure it's because new HTML 5 attribute, type="url". Better to remove it, since it's description (http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.url.html):

"The input element with a type attribute whose value is "url" represents a control for editing an **absolute URL** given in the element’s value."

Comment: @derigel works fine in current release of Chrome 4.1.249.1064 (45376) -- perhaps Chrome 5 beta is buggy?

Comment: Yes, I am at Chrome 5.0.375.29. And, in general, it's not buggy - just follows standard, which says that field with type="url" must contains absolute URL.