# Can't submit login via OpenId using Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, google-chrome

Hi there. Long time listener, first time caller. :)

I've set up my own OpenId server and I've been able to use my credentials to log into stackoverflow.com and associated sites, using Firefox.

Using Chrome though, I am unable to submit my credentials using the Log In button. It's like it doesn't have the submit code attached, so clicking it does nothing. Can't press Enter to submit either.

Anyone else experience this? I'm using Chrome 5.0.375.55 beta (extensions disabled) on Windows 7.

Comment: FWIW, Chrome worked for me when I was using something close to that version and is working now with 6.0.408.1 dev on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, but see

[Suggestion: use type="text" on the openid URL input field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49031/suggestion-use-typetext-on-the-openid-url-input-field)

and

[Suggestion: use type="url" on the openid URL input field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35070/suggestion-use-typeurl-on-the-openid-url-input-field)

for hilarity.

Comment: Wow, looks like fun! :) I've logged in successfully with Chrome now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Overflow Trilogy does not support beta versions of browsers (esp. Chrome) as a matter of policy. I suppose the Team's answer would be to ask you to use a released non-beta browser.

Comment: Good point. I have installed 5.0.375.55 (not beta) and have the same issue.