# OpenID login does not work on Data Explorer with Google Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, google-chrome, data-explorer

I can't login to [Data Explorer](http://odata.stackexchange.com/account/login) with Google Chrome. Firefox works just fine.

When I click "Log in" button or press enter after writing my OpenID, nothing happens.

I am using Windows Vista, Google Chrome 5.0.375.55 and Firefox 3.6.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome insists on the "http://" before the OpenId url.

Comment: You are right. But then there should be some kind of warning or help text...

Comment: Login seems to work without "http://" on Stackoverflow, though.

Comment: Juha Syrjälä: That's why Stack Overflow reverted the change to use `type="url"`; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35070/suggestion-use-typeurl-on-the-openid-url-input-field/36433#36433

Comment: ok I reverted the same change as well

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a blogger.com based custom domain openid to login and got this error:

```
Request-URI Too Large

The requested URL /accounts/TokenAuth... is too large to process.
```

When I switched to use the Google Account provider instead of http://blog.theg2.net it worked, so there was an easy workaround but I prefer using the blog url instead of Google Account. Low priority but just FYI...

Keep up the great work!